# How to show python/openCV outcome images on ssh-client, not in ssh server?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ssh, x11

I am connected to a ssh server using ssh -Y username@adress.
On the server I run python2.7 using IDLE.
If I use matplotlib I can see the outcome graphs on client. This suggests the graphical forwarding has no problem. 
However, when I am using OpenCV:

```
cv2.imshow('img_final', img_final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It opens and show the image in the ssh server screen, not in the client ssh computer.

I did search and research, and in response of typical trobleshooting:
- On my computer running client-ssh, echo $DISPLAY responds :0. It runs xterm.  -On my server ssh computer, My sshd_config file  seems to be ok (X11Forwarding yes). echo $DISPLAY shows localhost:10.0.

Moreover, I can use imageviewer such as 'feh' and shows images on client without any problem.

I do not think I have a configuration problem, because server is able to display graphics on client.

Is there a way to execute python scripts on server, and show outcome images from OpenCV directly on client (as MAtplotlib does) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is of use to you, you could do something like a continuous capture but storing each frame as an image:

```
    def deferred_init(self):
        self.total_frames = 200
        for i in range(self.total_frames):
            self.stream = self.camera.capture_sequence(
                ['image%02d.jpg' % i]
                )
        return self.stream
```

(This snippet was in an object, hence the self.x) This is assuming you have camera = PiCamera and the usual initialization as well. Anyway, once called a) your working dir will be cluttered (recommend making writing to a different folder) and b) you can view your images from ssh with whatever you prefer. This way tests that a capture is working but also allows you to view from ssh.